# KIVY - How do I bind behavior to when the screen position of a widget changes?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to use a scissor instruction to clip part of a widget. The widget has a ScatterView as an ancestor. I would like to recalculate the scissor rectangle when the ScatterView is dragged around. This should result in my widget having a new screen position, however it does not change the widget's position relative to it's parent. Can I be notified when the screen position of a widget changes?